# What to do after you get a CVE?

Tags: disclosure, cve

I recently reported a security vulnerability and it was patched. The patch (and associated issue) are both out in the open in a Github repo (aka public). I contacted cve-assign@mitre.org to get a CVE Identifier issued for the vulnerability. I have been issued a CVE Identifier.

Do I need to do anything else (e.g. supply Proof of Concept code etc), or am I done?

Comment: Just to clarify, mr.spuratic is correct and this is an open source project.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

<strike>Given you have referenced Github, I will assume this related to some type of</strike> As an open source project, a note to [oss-sec](http://oss-security.openwall.org/wiki/mailing-lists/oss-security) is a good idea. This will bring it to the attention of most upstream distributors.

You do not need to subscribe to post to oss-sec, but you should note carefully the etiquette/content guidelines in the link above. A rummage through [the archives](http://seclists.org/oss-sec/) should point you in the right direction, this one is a recent posting (from the list maintainer) the form of which you could usefully copy: 
 http://seclists.org/oss-sec/2015/q3/61

The NIST *National Vulnerability Database* is [driven by CVE data](https://cve.mitre.org/about/faqs.html#a2) and should be updated in the near future, they don't suggest how long it might take though. The [NVD FAQ](https://nvd.nist.gov/faq) also has some useful details, including contact procedures for missing or incorrect entries. I'd suggest giving it *at least two weeks* (based on empirical evidence) after you post to oss-sec before following up though, the CVE people tend to be busy.

Comment: Do I need to do anything additional to add the information to: https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=[CVE ID Here]? Right now it does not show up but is that just a matter of waiting until they update the website?

Comment: Updated. I believe you just need to wait, posting to oss-sec *might* help, but it depends on the scope and severity of your issue (and every other issue currently in the queue).